# Prestashop 1.6 own registration form in a custom module

Tags: php, prestashop

I've created a module with a custom page. Now on this page I want to add a possibility to register a new account without redirection to the default login page. I've searched for the solution but there is not much about this. I need some tips how to do this.

Comment: Copy `controllers/front/AuthController.php` `init()`, `initContent()` or else functions you need and modify it to meet your needs, your custom page variables and URLs.

Comment: Thanks, I let you know if this will help me solve my problem.